# Facebook Graph API: How to add vote links to a wall post?

Tags: php, facebook

I am building a Facebook app with voting included. With it I want to send a message to the user's wall including some text and two or more links.

I also want to control the link text so that I can get links like "Yes" and "No".

The first thing I tried was posting regular -tags, but (no surprise) that didn't work. I have seen other apps do this though. Are there any special tags that allow links?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that you're using the Graph API and already have publish a post working.

I think the `properties` property might be what you are looking for (it is left out of the new [API reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) but is described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments)). This allows links although they might not be formatted quite how you want. Example:

```
$data = array (
           'name'       => ...,
           'link'       => ...,
           'properties' => array (
                              'Yes' => array  (
                                        'text' => 'Vote',
                                        'href' => 'http://www.example.com?vote=yes'
                                       ),
                              'No' => array  (
                                        'text' => 'Vote',
                                        'href' => 'http://www.example.com?vote=no'
                                       )
                           ),
         ); //And whatever other properties you want
$facebook->api('/uid/feed', 'POST', $data);
```

The properties will appear after beneath description in the post and come out like the following:

> Yes: [Vote](http://www.example.com?vote=yes)